# ES6 class getters broken in ember 2.3?

Tags: ember.js

I'm having some weird behavior after upgrading from ember 2.2 to 2.3. I've narrowed it down to the getters in an ES6 class.

If I have a class like this, calling `foo.prop` will return `undefined`.

```
class Foo {
  get prop() {
    return 10;
  }
}
```

Everything works if I change the class like so:

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.prop = 10;
  }
}
```

I'm using `foo.prop` in some computed properties and/or templates.

What is going on here?

Comment: how are you instantiating Foo ? just `var foo = new Foo();` ?

Comment: @Bek yes, then `foo` gets passed around to components. Only the class getters which are observed seem to have a problem.

Comment: @dwickern Seeing the same. Do you mind posting an issue on the Ember.js repo (https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/)? I think it will have more success there than here.

Comment: @yorbro I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/13011). If you have any info to add, that would help a lot.